# HTTP to HTTPS and non-WWW to www with multiple domains

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https, no-www

I can't find the answer anywhere for this.

I have a page with multiple domains for multi-language purpose and i have a sub-domain for each so I can develop locally (**dev.**)

Before the need of HTTPS it all worked fine redirecting from **non-WWW** to **WWW** and working locally with "**dev.**". This was (is) my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain1.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain3.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain3.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So what i had was: every non-subdomain woud redirect to www

Now i need the domain **domain1.com** to always redirect to **https** and also to **www** when there's no subdomain, so the **dev.** can still work.

examples:

```
http://domain1.com -> https://www.domain1.com/
http://www.domain1.com -> https://www.domain1.com/
http://www.domain2.com -> http://www.domain2.com/
http://domain3.com -> http://www.domain3.com/
http://dev.domain3.com -> http://dev.domain3.com/
http://dev.domain1.com -> https://dev.domain1.com/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should cover it!

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev\.domain1\.com

RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:[^dev]*|dev.+)(\.domain1\.com)
RewriteRule (.*) https://www%1%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.domain1.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain3.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain3.com/$1 [R=301,L]`
```

- List item